# Triple integral in cylindrical coordinates

Tags: calculus

Solve $$\int\limits_{0}^{3}\int\limits_{-\sqrt{9-y^2}}^{\sqrt{9-y^2}}\int\limits_{0}^{9-3\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}dzdxdy.$$

Update:
The problem is setting up the integral. What I have tried was $$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\int\limits_{-3}^{3}\int\limits_{0}^{9-3r}dzrdrd\theta.$$
It gave me $54\pi$ and I don't think it's right.

Comment: @Sigur are you sure?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't see the $r$ after $dz$. Now $\int _{0}^{\pi }\!\int _{-3}^{3}\!\int _{0}^{9-3\,r}\!1{dz}r{dr}\,{d\theta}
=-54\,\pi$

Answer (score 2):

Without computations, one could recognize this integral as the volume of one half of circular cone with height $9$ and base radius $3$. The volume   is $$\frac12 \frac{\pi 3^2\cdot 9}{3}   = \frac{27\pi}{2} $$

To set up integrals, begin with the inner variable, $z$: 
$$ \int_{0}^{9-3\sqrt{x^2+y^2}}\,dz = \int_0^{9-3r}\,r\,dz$$
The $x,y$ limits describe the upper half of disk of radius $3$ (because $y\ge 0$). This means $0\le r\le 3$ and $0\le \theta \le \pi$.  So, the result is 
$$\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{3}\int\limits_{0}^{9-3r}r\,dz\, dr\,d\theta
=\int\limits_{0}^{\pi}\int\limits_{0}^{3} (9r-3r^2)\,dr\,d\theta
= \pi (9\cdot 3^2/2-3^3) = \frac{27 \pi}{2}
$$

Negative values of $r$ are sometimes useful in drawing polar curves, but they should *never* be used in integration.